# Scraping a Index of text into ordered folders

Tags: python, web-scraping, hierarchical, gpt-4

I've been trying to scrape a web page index.
Seeking advice or avenues to explore for how to go about this task.

The index is side by side another index with the same names.
But that left index leads to videos or forums which I dont need.
I want to capture the right Index which leads to chapters and text commentary.

This is the page https://www.theseason.org/nt.htm
To the right is the index of Bible books I want scraped.
Excluding entries just below it.

I've been using Chat GPT 4 having poor results so far.

What I've tried:
I dabbled with python and was only able to get a list of links of the index.
But it was missing three books in that index for unknown reasons. And it didn't capture any chapters or text contents.

I've tried WinHTTrack application to scrape the html files for me.
That was the best results so far and may return to it.

But I'm drawing a blank how to create the hierarchical folder structure which contains the text for each chapter.
Or I may manually do this.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: "*I've been using Chat GPT 4 having poor results so far.*" As you've discovered, ChatGPT is not a serious programming resource and should not be used or regarded as one. It frequently produces inefficient, buggy, or outright non-working code, and often creates references to modules that simply don't exist. Your time would be better spent reading more foundational material about the language and libraries you're looking to use to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how you can get the 4th column (names + links) into pandas dataframe.

Afterwards you can iterate over these links and get information you need from them.

```py
import re

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.theseason.org/nt.htm"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

table = soup.select_one("table:not(:has(table))")

data = []
for row in table.select("tr"):
    tds = row.select("td")
    if tds[3].a:
        name = re.sub(r"\s{2,}", " ", tds[3].get_text(strip=True, separator=" "))
        link = tds[3].a["href"]

        data.append((name, link))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["name", "link"])
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
          name                                               link
0      Genesis          https://theseason.org/genesis/genesis.htm
1       Exodus            https://theseason.org/exodus/exodus.htm
2    Leviticus  https://www.theseason.org/leviticus/leviticus.htm
3      Numbers      https://www.theseason.org/numbers/numbers.htm
4  Deuteronomy            https://www.theseason.org/deut/deut.htm
```